# Get the number of days and determine which month from the between two dates

Tags: php, arrays, date, logic

I know it is very crazy, but I am still asking for your solution.

Now, I have two dates: let say start date: 2017-02-01 and end date: 2017-04-01.

If I compare the end date with the start date, of course I would get 60 days (includes one day of 2017-02-01 for itself).

Assume I don't know what month and how many days do the months have between these 2 dates. Erm...is there anyway to determine the days and month... clearly?

Something like this:

1. 2017-02-01 => 2017-02-28 = 28 days AND this is February
2. 2017-03-01 => 2017-03-31 = 31 days AND this is March
3. 2017-04-01 => 2017-04-01 = 1 day AND this is April

I could only find the days between two dates in PHP, and of course it is easier than this one. I think this one already covers the array concept, and already beyond my IQ XD.

I need your help, prove yourselves by this solving this question, thank you so much! Much appreciated.

In simpler: What I wanted to find is -- I don't want to find the day between two dates, I wanna find what month and how many days for each month between these two dates.

P/S: I don't have any code for this, because I don't even know how to start to code this.

Comment: "I don't know what month", well, if you have the dates, you know the month.

Comment: 4. 2017-05-01 => 2017-07-01 = 61 days AND this was May, June, July?

Comment: @JulienLachal just let's say.

Comment: @mulquin yes something like this, and determine how many do they have (every month).

Comment: BTW it's just 60 days. You also should exaplain what you like to solve. To just get the days, substract the strt date from the end date. If you have just the days with no month, there is no single solution, because there are several combinations whit the same result. You'd better explan what you try to achieve.

Comment: @KurtLudikovsky what I wanted to find as I mention above, I don't want to find the day between two dates, I wanna find what month and how many days for each month between these two dates.

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can use date_diff function. date_diff function count the day between two date, so you can add 2 to count your date too..

```
$date1=date_create("2017-02-01");
$date2=date_create("2017-04-01");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);

$res =  $diff->format("%R%a days");
echo ($res + 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
$from_date = "2017-02-01";
$to_date = "2017-04-01";
$start = $month = strtotime($from_date);
$tmp = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,date('m',strtotime($to_date)),date('Y',strtotime($to_date)));
$end = strtotime(date('Y-m',strtotime($to_date)).'-'.$tmp);
while($month < $end){
    $days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,date('m',$month),date('Y',$month));
    if(date('m',$start) == date('m',$month)) {
        $days = $days - date('d',$start) + 1;
    } else if(date('m',$end) == date('m',$month)) {
        $days = date('d',strtotime($to_date));
    }
    echo "Days :".$days." Month :".date('F',$month);
    echo '<br>';
    $month = strtotime("+1 month", $month);
}
```

output will looks like below

```
Days :28 Month :February Days :31 Month :March Days :01 Month :April
```

Answer (score -1):

PHP has some quite powerful DateTime classes and functions.

```
<?php

$start = new DateTime('2017-05-01');
$end = new DateTime('2017-07-03');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

$output = ['daysTotal' => 0, 'months' => []];
$months = [];
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    if (!in_array($dt->format("F"), $months)) {
        $month = ['name' => $dt->format("F"), 'days' => cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $dt->format("n"), $dt->format("Y"))];
        $output['months'][] = $month;
        $months[] = $dt->format("F");

    }
    $output['daysTotal']++;
}

var_dump($output);
```

This will output:

```
array(2) {
  ["daysTotal"]=>
  int(63)
  ["months"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(3) "May"
      ["days"]=>
      int(31)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "June"
      ["days"]=>
      int(30)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "July"
      ["days"]=>
      int(31)
    }
  }
}
```

Note: If you do between 2017-05-01 and 2017-06-01, it will not register June in the months array.